# Sigmoid function return NaN in Java

Tags: java, nan, logistic-regression

I am trying to create a logistic regression algorithm in java but when I calculate the logarithm of the likelihood it is always returning NaN. My method which calculates the logarithm looks like this :

```
//Calculate log likelihood on given data
private double getLogLikelihood(double cat, double[] x) {
    return cat * Math.log(findProbability(x))
         + (1 - cat) * Math.log(1 - findProbability(x));
}
```

And the findProbability method is just take an instance from the dataset and returning the sigmoid funcion result which is between 0 and 1.

```
//Calculate the sum of w * x for each weight and attribute
//call the sigmoid function with that s
public double findProbability(double[] x){
    double s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++){
        if(i >= x.length) break;
            s += this.weights[i] * x[i];        
    }
    return sigmoid(s);
}

private double sigmoid(double s){
    return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-s));
}
```

Moreover, my starting weights are :

```
[-0.2982955509135178, -0.4984900460081106, -1.816880187922516, -2.7325608512266073, 0.12542715714800834, 0.1516078084483485, 0.27631147403449774, 0.1371611094778011, 0.16029832096058613, 0.3117065974657231, 0.04262385176091778, 0.1948263133838624, 0.10788353525185314, 0.770608588466501, 0.2697281907888033, 0.09920694325563077, 0.003224073601703939, 0.021573742410541247, 0.21528348692817675, 0.3275511757298476, -0.1500597314893408, -0.7221692528386277, -2.062544912370121, 1.4315146889363015, 0.2522133355419722, 0.23919315019065995, 0.3200037377021523, 0.059466770771758076, 0.04012493980772944, 0.2553236501265919]
```

Finally, an instance from my dataset is :[`M,17.99,10.38,122.8,1001,0.1184,0.2776,0.3001,0.1471,0.2419,0.07871,1.095,0.9053,8.589,153.4,0.006399,0.04904,0.05373,0.01587,0.03003,0.006193,25.38,17.33,184.6,2019,0.1622,0.6656,0.7119,0.2654,0.4601,0.1189`]

I tried to initialize the starting weightss with different random numbers but thats didnt solve the problem.

Comment: Did you check the value of s?

Comment: Yes, it was between 2358.7420164286 and 3522.2404828342

Comment: It might be that this function `Math.log(1 - findProbability(x)` is giving you negative numbers. What means that your `findProbability(x)` returns values greater than one. Check there

Comment: e^(-3522) is pretty close to 0, so is your sigmoid function returning 1. Hence you're asking for log(0)?

Answer (score 0):

NaN is a result of dividing by zero or calling Math.log on a non-positive number, so u should try and find where exactly this happens. I suggest debugging or adding code to print the values of which u take the logarithm/dividy by.

EDIT: it seems it is a rounding error: exp(-s) will return a result so small that added with 1 it will still remain 1. This causes the logarithm to return -Inf. I'd suggest u try and find a mathematical way to solve this by trying to perhaps to approximate the log of the exponential.

Comment: I think that Math.log cant be called for a negative number as it takes the result from sigmoid funcion which returns values between 0 and 1.

Comment: I just tested your code, leaving out the M in the instance of your dataset (as I have no idea how it's calculated). This gave me a decent result when calling getloglikelihood(0.5,dataset), so perhaps the M in your dataset is already NaN before calculation?

Comment: I am converting M to 1 so it does not affect anything

Answer (score 0):

The arithematic is causing  a rounding error leaving you with 1.

```
double b = 1 + Math.exp(-3522);
```

b will be equal to 1, because otherwise you will need too many sig figs. You'll have to approximate the value to keep the precision. 1/(1+s) ~= 1 - s; Which means you need to calculate log(1) and log(s).

edit: sorry, I made a mistake, it appears Math.exp(-3522) is evaluated as 0 after rounding. Ill leave this answer because Math.exp(-x) might be too small to add to 1, or it might just be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem so I post it here:
I added an overflow check:

```
private double sigmoid(double s){
    if(s>20){
        s=20;
    }else if(s<-20){
        s=-20;
    }
    double exp = Math.exp(s);
    return exp/(1+exp);
}
```

Also changing `1/(1+Math.exp(s)` to `exp/(1+exp)` proved to be more stable in small disturbances of inputs.